# Managing Ajax Session Timed Out

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC4 application with a page containing a number of Ajax actions.  I am trying to deal with what happens after a session expires.

At present, I have code which forces a "FormsAuthentication.SignOut()" running on Session_Start(), if the context reports the current request isAuthenticated.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();         // Drop all the information held in the session
        // now continue with request....
    }
}
```

The next piece is an Override for "HandleUnauthorizedRequest", which should trap the Unauthorized request, test if it was an ajax request, and proceed if not, but to otherwise return a specific JSON to indicate the failure.

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = new { ajaxUnauthorizedMessage = "sorry, but your session has expired..." }, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
    } else {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a global jquery ajaxSuccess handler, which tests for my message above, and alerts the user to the issue, and then forces a reload (which should cause MVC to redirect to the Login page),

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (result) {
    if (result.ajaxUnauthorizedMessage) {
        alert(result.ajaxUnauthorizedMessage);
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work that way.  What happens instead is the Session Start "signout", followed by execution of the [Authorize] decorated Action Method (which then fails because of a dependency on the lost session).

Perplexingly, if I then make a SECOND call to the same Ajax operation (without waiting for the timeout on the new session), the second call is intercepted by the "HandleUnauthorizedRequest" method, and then everything works as I expected the first one to( well, not everyting, the ajaxSuccess global handler fails to pick up the second call, even after catching the first, but that is something to worry about after I get the primary issue resolved).

Additionally, the same behavior is seen even without ajax.  The signout fires, but I'm 'pre-authorized', and so the action fires anyways.

How can I successfully un-authorize, so that the "HandleUnauthorizedRequest" fires when I expect it to?

### Edit 1

On a whim, I edited Session_Start(), and had it remove all the Request and Response Cookies.  I was surprised to find that the auth-required Action method still fires, and even more surprised that the Cookies were all back!  They persisted after deletion!  I guess Session_Start isn't dealing with the real Request object?  Well, it was worth a try, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I approached this a little differently than you have.  Here's how my solution works:

I created an `Auth` method on my `AccountController` that returns a JSON response of 'true' or 'false'

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[DoNotResetAuthCookie]
[OutputCache(NoStore=true, Duration=0)]
public JsonResult Auth()
{
    return Json(Request.IsAuthenticated, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I implemented the same `Session_Start()` that you have implemented.

Finally, in my javascript, I periodically check to see if I'm still authenticated, if not, then I redirected the page as follows:

```
function redirectOnNotAuthorized(authUrl, redirectUrl) {
    $.get(authUrl)
         .done(function (data) {
             var isStillAuthorized = data || false;
             if (!isStillAuthorized) {
                 window.location.href = redirectUrl;
             }
         })
        .fail(function () {
            window.location.href = redirectUrl;
        });
}

$(function() {
    var timer, duration;
    duration = 20000;
    window.stillAuthorized = function stillAuthorized() {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(stillAuthorized, duration);
        redirectOnNotAuthorized("Account/Auth", "Account/LogOn");
    };
    timer = setTimeout(stillAuthorized, duration);
});
```

**Edit1**:

I learned something...  In the `redirectOnNotAuthorized` function it also works to set

```
windows.location.reload()
```

instead of

```
windows.location.href = redirectUrl;
```

thereby simplifying the code and making it less dependent on the app.

Comment: thanks!  I'l be revisiting this topic again shortly, and I think I'll give your method a shot.  It looks similar to some other ideas I was tossing around.  Appreciate it!